# Creating a SL/TP based on ticks with flexible rules in Pinescript/Tradingview

Tags: trading, tradingview-api

I have created a stop loss and take profit based on ticks

```
sl_inp = input.int(10, title='SL in Ticks')

tp_inp = input.int(10, title='TP in Ticks')

strategy.exit("Long Exit", "Long Entry", loss=sl_inp, profit=tp_inp)
```

The issue is that I can't figure out how to add additional rules around this.
For example, if candle closes above TP, leave position open and move SL to TP level.

Also I could just use the below to get the same outcome as above it seems but again, it doesn't help much.

```
strategy.exit("Long Exit", "Long Entry", loss=10, profit=10)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't just move SL to TP level cause at the moment price close above it, the TP level is already hitted and position is closed.
Try this:

```
sl_inp = input.int(10, title='SL in Ticks')
tp_inp = input.int(10, title='TP in Ticks')
stopl = strategy.position_avg_price - sl_inp
if crossover(close, (strategy.position_avg_price + tp_inp))
    stopl := strategy.position_avg_price + tp_inp
    tp_inp := tp_inp + tp_inp

strategy.exit("Long Exit", "Long Entry", stop = stopl)
```

But this means that you TP wont work if it's simply touched.